# How to make the WP admin menu responsive and like the ubuntu menu, with top horizontal menu/quicklinks?

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, responsive-design, dashboard, user-friendly

The objective is to make the WP admin menu look like:

[image: 1]

The top nav has the quicklinks that everyone can relate to with pictures.

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [thedesignwork.com](http://cdn.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/admin-panel-horizontal-menu.png))</sub>

Easily clickable if accessed by a tablet.

[image: 3]

Notifications are served with colored numbers.

[image: 4]
<sub>(source: [thedesignwork.com](http://cdn.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/admin-popup-design.png))</sub>

Including customizing popup displays.

Where the start isn't the normal analytics widgets and overview but an app like place to offer all the extra "apps" the admin menu has. It'll have to be customizable where users can decide if to access the normal dashboard or this menu:

[image: 5]
<sub>(source: [alexsantidote.com](http://alexsantidote.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/admin_menu.png))</sub>

All plugins I came across only changes the WP logo, the color of the admin hover bar, and some basic css stuff. Can somebody point me into the right direction? I'm new to wordpress and hopefully this is possible..

The next step would be making it into a network activated plugin (I'll ask that another time..).

> http://www.thedesignwork.com/admin-panel-psd-template/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is the WordPress Codex's Page on [Creating Admin Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes).  This is not going to be a trivial task, though.  Just warning you.

Comment: I see. I found that doing this would be easier on Modx. Keeping this thread related I created another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771738/how-would-wp-plugins-need-to-be-recoded-in-order-to-work-on-modx.

However, if transferring the plugins (and sub-domain activating across a network [like wordpres]) is harder than doing this, I'll get back to you after delving into the WP Codex site you linked to.