# How would WP plugins need to be recoded in order to work on Modx?

Tags: wordpress, modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution

Lets say, I want an affiliate plugin that I bought for WP to work on Modx. What are the procedures to follow? Yes, you can assume that all the plugins I bought use php, javascript, and jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactoring your plugin to modx snippets and chunks  - http://www.cmslesstraveled.com/index/tutorials/refactoring-a-simple-php-application-for-modx.html

Answer (score 0):

> You can use internal Wordpress functions by including this file
>   include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
>
> You can try including the file in one of your modx templates and then
>   see if it gives you access to your affiliate plugin functions.
>
> Vice-Versa you could include modx into your wordpress theme files by
>   adding this code.
>
> define('MODX_CORE_PATH', 'full/path/to/your/modx/core/');
>   define('MODX_CONFIG_KEY', 'config'); require_once MODX_CORE_PATH .
>   'model/modx/modx.class.php'; $modx= new modX();
>   $modx->initialize('mgr');
>
> This will give you access to the $modx object and all it's wonders.

Source: http://www.quora.com/MODX-CMS/How-would-WordPress-plugins-need-to-be-recoded-in-order-to-work-in-MODX